# SugarCRM: Custom Dashlet addition

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I made custom module with dashlet and want to add this dashlet from custom module view.

It it possible to add custom made dashlet programmaticaly to home layout?

Comment: Well, it should be there automatically. When you navigate to "Home" and click on "Add Dashlet" in the menu you should see it in the list. If it's not there it has been patched out intentionally.